# Vowpal Wabbit varinfo and ngrams : non-existent combinations

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to use vw to find words or phrases that predict if someone will open an email.  The target is 1 if they opened the email and 0 otherwise.  My data looks like this:

```
1 |A this is a test
0 |A this test is only temporary
1 |A i bought a new polo shirt
1 |A that was a great online sale
```

I put it into a file called 'test1.txt' and run the following code to do ngrams of 2 and also output variable information:

```
C:\~\vw>perl vw-varinfo.pl -V --ngram 2 test1.txt >> out.txt
```

When I look at the output there are bigrams that I don't see in the original data.  Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something.

Output:

```
FeatureName            HashVal   MinVal   MaxVal    Weight   RelScore
A^a                     239656     0.00     1.00   +0.1664    100.00%
A^is                      7514     0.00     1.00   +0.0772     46.38%
A^test                   12331     0.00     1.00   +0.0772     46.38%
A^this                  169573     0.00     1.00   +0.0772     46.38%
A^bought                245782     0.00     1.00   +0.0650     39.06%
A^i                     245469     0.00     1.00   +0.0650     39.06%
A^new                    51974     0.00     1.00   +0.0650     39.06%
A^polo                   48680     0.00     1.00   +0.0650     39.06%
A^shirt                  73882     0.00     1.00   +0.0650     39.06%
A^great                 220692     0.00     1.00   +0.0610     36.64%
A^online                147727     0.00     1.00   +0.0610     36.64%
A^sale                  242707     0.00     1.00   +0.0610     36.64%
A^that                  206586     0.00     1.00   +0.0610     36.64%
A^was                   223274     0.00     1.00   +0.0610     36.64%
A^a^bought              216990     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^bought^great            7122     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^great^i               190625     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^i^is                   76227     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^is^new                140536     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^new^online             69117     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^online^only           173498     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^only^polo              51059     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^polo^sale             131483     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^sale^shirt            191329     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^shirt^temporary        81555     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^temporary^test         90632     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^test^that              13689     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^that^this             127863     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
A^this^was               22011     0.00     0.00   +0.0000      0.00%
Constant                116060     0.00     0.00   +0.1465      0.00%
A^only                   62951     0.00     1.00   -0.0490    -29.47%
A^temporary              44641     0.00     1.00   -0.0490    -29.47%
```

For instance, `^bought^great` never actually occurs in any of the original input rows.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in vw-varinfo.

This can be verified by running `vw` alone with `--invert_hash`:

```
$ vw --ngram 2 test1.txt --invert_hash train.ih

$ grep '^bought^great' train.ih
# no output
```

The quick partial work-around is to treat all features with a weight of 0.0 as highly suspect, and probably bogus.  Unfortunately, there are some features that are missing too because `vw-varinfo` knows nothing about `--ngram`.

I really need to rewrite `vw-varinfo`. `vw` changed a lot since `vw-varinfo` was written, plus `vw-varinfo` was written sub-optimally repeating a lot of the cross-feature logic that's already in `vw` itself.  The new implementation which I have in mind should be significanly more efficient and less vulnerable to these kinds of bugs.

This project was put on hold due to more urgent stuff.  Hope to find some time to correct this this year.

Unrelated tip: since you're doing binary classification, you should use labels in {-1, 1} rather than in {0,1} and use `--loss_function logistic` for best results.